# The concise way to initialize an array of reference type object

Tags: c#, linq

I wonder if there is better way to initialize an array of reference type object, like this.

```
Queue<int>[] queues = new Queue<int>[10];
for (int i = 0; i < queues.Length; i++)
    queues[i] = new Queue<int>();
```

I tried Enumerable.Repeat, but all elements in the array refer to same instance,

```
Queue<int>[] queues = Enumerable.Repeat(new Queue<int>(), 10).ToArray();
```

I also tried Array.ForEach, but it doesn't work without ref keyword:

```
Queue<int>[] queues = Array.ForEach(queues, queue => queue = new Queue<int>());
```

any other idea?

Comment: Personally I think your first example is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Agreed.  What's wrong with a loop?

Comment: I know my first example is totally fine, just curious if there is another option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(_=>new Queue<int>()).ToArray()
```

But IMO your first example is perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. Just factor it out into a utility method:

```
// CommonExtensions.cs
public static T[] NewArray<T> (int length) where T : class, new ()
{
    var result = new T[length] ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < result.Length ; ++i)
         result[i] = new T () ;
    return result ;
}

// elsewhere
var queues = Extensions.NewArray<Queue<int>> (10) ;
```

Comment: @L.B - It looks like it would return an array of Queue<int>

Comment: @hatchet yep, that's exactly what the question is asking for.

Comment: IMO the API bloat by such specialized helper functions is usually not worth it.

Comment: This isn't API. Declare it in an internal class if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same answer - to use a loop. But you can make it as an extension method for general purpose:

```
    public static void Init<T>(this IList<T> array )
    {
        if (array == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
            array[i] = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
```

and the just call it:

```
        Queue<int>[] queues = new Queue<int>[10];
        queues.Init();
```